# IOS Simulator bug with my view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, simulator

I want to believe this is a simulator bug, but, can somebody please explain what is going on?

Im running a simple View on my storyboard: (as you can see, the view with green background is my superview). The thing is when I run my app on a simulator (sometimes, not always) my superview doesn't get scaled and I get a black screen!! My view has checked true the Use Autolayout field, cause some things inside need to have constraints.

[image: my view]

[image]

[image]

I can't give constraints to my view because, **it's the superview**

And yes, I have debugged with the UI and this is the thing, my superview is not resizing.

[image]

Comment: Give a leading, trailing, up, and bottom constraint to your view to resolve this issue.

Comment: It's my superview, it's supposed to reescale without constraints, right?. I'm going to edit my answer in order to avoid this type of responses.

Comment: If this happens you can ‘debug the view hierarchy’ (the iphone shaped button in your debug bar) to see how things get laid out on the simulator.

Comment: I already did! -> My problem is that my superview is not resizing

Comment: Did you tried added constraints to it??? because in my case this resolved

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved, for sure is a bug of Xcode. For me was very strange, so, I decided to delete my View Controller and add all my elements again.